# How do I rotate a single windows application 90 degrees?

Tags: desktop-application

I was toying with a website design that is supposed to run on a portrait-oriented wide-screen. I can simulate this by rotating the entire desktop via the videocard settings, but that's fiddly and annoying when the monitor itself is landscape.

Googling didn't result in anything useful, so I throw it out here. Has anyone ever tried this? Or am I mad for even thinking of it? I'd think it should be possible to write a layer between a webbrowser and windows that rotates everything 90 degrees, leaving the browser none-the-wiser. Someone must have considered this before me? :)

Comment: I think your first idea is correct. That layer is called a "video driver".